# Error al imprimir un arreglo con PHP

Tags: php, array-bidimensional

intento realizar un arreglo multidimensional con PHP, para simular las sillas de un teatro.  En principio quiero hacerlo con letras pero luego quiero en vez de ellas poner ICONOS, la idea es simular la compra, reserva o liberación de un puesto en el teatro.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De momento en el recorrido del `for`, rellené el contenido el `<li>` con un valor directo que es 1, tengo el siguiente código.

```
<?php 
    $sillas = array(
        'A'=>array("libre","libre","libre","libre","libre"),
        'B'=>array("libre","libre","libre","libre","libre"),
        'C'=>array("libre","libre","libre","libre","libre"),
        'D'=>array("libre","libre","libre","libre","libre"),
        'E'=>array("libre","libre","libre","libre","libre"));

        foreach ($sillas as $key => $value) {
            echo "<ul id='sillas'>";
            echo "$key";
            for ($indice=0; $indice < count($value); $indice++) { 
            echo "<li>1</li>";
            }
            echo "</ul>";
            }
?>
```

Pero al momento de cambiar el valor 1 del `<li>` por el contenido de la variable `$value` entonces recibo un error en el navegador, que no comprendo el porque.

```
<?php 
    $sillas = array(
        'A'=>array("libre","libre","libre","libre","libre"),
        'B'=>array("libre","libre","libre","libre","libre"),
        'C'=>array("libre","libre","libre","libre","libre"),
        'D'=>array("libre","libre","libre","libre","libre"),
        'E'=>array("libre","libre","libre","libre","libre"));

        foreach ($sillas as $key => $value) {
            echo "<ul id='sillas'>";
            echo "$key";
            for ($indice=0; $indice < count($value); $indice++) { 
            echo "<li>$value</li>";
            }
            echo "</ul>";
            }
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les agradezco si me pueden ayudar, pues la idea es luego de mostrar las sillas o los puestos, poder elegir desde el formulario la letra y el numero del puesto a comprar, pero adicionalmente poder creo que con javascript, sobreponer un `<div>` que indique cuando el puesto esté comprado o reservado, adicionalmente si esta en uno de esos dos estados poder mostrar una alerta que impida volver a reservarlo o comprarlo. No se si me hago comprender con la idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajusta el codigo en la parte donde se muestra el contenido. Estas intentando mostrar `$value`, que corresponde al `array` de la fila que estas mostrando (por ello el mensaje *"Array to string conversion"*).

Usa `$value[$indice]` donde desees mostrar el valor. Ademas , creo que el primer elemento de la fila deberia ser tambien un `<li></li>` para mantener la estructura.

```
<?php 
$sillas = array(
    'A'=>array("libre","libre","libre","libre","libre"),
    'B'=>array("libre","libre","libre","libre","libre"),
    'C'=>array("libre","libre","libre","libre","libre"),
    'D'=>array("libre","libre","libre","libre","libre"),
    'E'=>array("libre","libre","libre","libre","libre"));

    foreach ($sillas as $key => $value) {
        echo "<ul id='sillas'>";
        echo "<li>$key</li>"; // si esta dentro de <ul> deberia ser <li></li>
        for ($indice=0; $indice < count($value); $indice++) { 
        echo "<li>{$value[$indice]}</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
        }
?>
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias por tu ayuda me sirvió y solucioné.